# Ошибка Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function =при добавление пользователя

Tags: php

При добавлении пользователя отображается ошибка

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MyForm\QueryBuilder::upLoadImage(), 0 passed in /var/www/form/src/QueryBuilder.php on line 43 and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/form/src/QueryBuilder.php on line 19
( ! ) ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MyForm\QueryBuilder::upLoadImage(), 0 passed in /var/www/form/src/QueryBuilder.php on line 43 and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/form/src/QueryBuilder.php on line 19
```

QueryBuilder.php

```
 ?php


namespace MyForm;
use \PDO;
use \PDOException;

class QueryBuilder
{
    public $pdo;

    function __construct()
    {
        //$this->pdo =new PDO($this->$dsn, $this->$db_user, $this->$db_pass);
        $this->pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=192.168.100.219; dbname=default", "default", "secret");
    }
    //Список задач

    function upLoadImage ($image)  {
        $extension = pathinfo($image['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = uniqid() . "." . $extension;
        move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], "uploads/" . $filename);
        return $filename;
        print_r($filename);

    }


    //Сохранение новой задачи
    function addTask ($firstName, $lastName, $thrName, $email, $address, $kurs, $faculty, $saveinfo, $whois, $zip) {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, thrname, email, address, kurs, faculty, saveinfo, whois, zip, image) 
                    VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :thrName, :email, :address, :kurs, :faculty, :saveinfo, :whois, :zip, :image)");
        $statement->bindValue(':firstName', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':thrName', $thrName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':kurs', $kurs, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $statement->bindValue(':faculty', $faculty,PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $statement->bindValue(':saveinfo',$saveinfo,PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $statement->bindValue(':whois', $whois,PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $statement->bindValue(':zip', $zip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':image', $this->upLoadImage());
        $statement->execute(); //true || false
        var_dump($this->pdo->lastInsertId('users_id_seq'));
    }
```

add.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use MyForm\QueryBuilder;
$db = new QueryBuilder();
$db->upLoadImage($_FILES['image']);
$db->addTask($_POST['firstName'], $_POST['lastName'],$_POST['thrName'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['address'],
    $_POST['kurs'], $_POST['faculty'],$_POST['saveinfo'],$_POST['whois'], $_POST['zip']);
```

Подскажите причину ошибки

Comment: Написано же понятно - нужно передать в функцию один аргумент, передано ноль. Даже номер строки указан.

Answer (score 0):

В методе `addTask` вызывается метод `upLoadImage`, который требует на вход один аргумент, а у вас в методе ничего не подаётся. Ошибка на это указывает